# Reorder Leaflet layers

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have 3 layers, one GeoJSON that is used with leaflet-draw and two (vector and canvas/heatmap) that just display overlays.

My problem is, the overlays get added later dynamically with the layer-control, while the GeoJSON layer is always there. When the overlays get added, some of the draw features and general interaction with the GeoJSON layer top to work, because my overlays are always on top.

**How can I get the GeoJSON layer back to the front?**

Using `layer.bringToFront()` didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If the layers are being added through the layer control, you can keep your GeoJSON layer on top by bumping it back using `.bringToFront()` each time an `overlayadd` event is fired:

```
map.on('overlayadd', function() {
    yourGeoJsonLayerName.bringToFront();
});
```

A somewhat unwieldy example fiddle is here:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/yt65dkyt/

Though layer ordering can be handled more gracefully in the Leaflet 1.0 betas by assigning layers to panes with a persistent zIndex, it looks like Leaflet Draw doesn't officially support 1.0 yet, so `.bringToFront` it is!

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work because I have some custom layers. Will have to look into `bringToFront()` to get this working, I guess. But thanks :)

Comment: If layers are being added by a means other than the layer control, you may be able to keep the draw layer on top using `map.on('layeradd' ...` instead.

Comment: The problem isn't getting the layers on an add (control or otherwise) the problem is, that `bringToFront()` doesn't bring the layer to the front.

Comment: If you are still looking for a solution, it would be probably worth sharing what kind of custom layers you have and how you put them on map.